# Id variable getting undefined Asp.net ajex

Tags: asp.net, ajax

inside the  get_category_details function retrieve id successfully i check through console.log working well. but when i passed the id into function addProject() it displyed look like that undefined

**{fname: 'Dhan',age: '3443', id: 'undefined'}**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfTyc.jpg)

when user click edit button it goes to  function get_category_details and show the data in to relevant textboxs and id image attached above.

```
  "sTitle": "Edit",
     "mData": "id",
     "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
      return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" onclick="get_category_details(' + mData + ')  ">Edit</button>';
      }
```

**get_category_details**

```
 function get_category_details(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'edit_return.asmx/doSome',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                 //   console.log(data);
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                    isNew = false;

                   id = data.d[0].id;                   


                    $('#fname').attr('value', data.d[0].fname);
                    $('#age').attr('value', data.d[0].age);

                    alert(id);
                }
            });
        }
```

**this how getting id** I checked through an alert message displayed successfully but it won't pass in to Addproject() method it displyed undefined

```
    function addProject() {               

   $.ajax({           
                type: _method,
                url: 'update.aspx/doSomething',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: '" + id + "'}",

                success: function (data) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without seeing the whole code it's hard to tell where the problem is, do you have `var id = ....` outside of `addProject()` scope? As `get_category_details(id)` already gets the parameter when it gets called. I don't know when you will be calling the `addProject()` function, but why not call it on `$.ajax` `success` and pass the `data.d[0].id` to it? or before declaring any of your functions have a variable `var idForProject = ''` and then inside the `success` do `idForProject = data.d[0].id` and edit `addProject()` to `var dataValue = { "fname": $('#fname').val(), "age": $('#age').val(), "id": idForProject };`

Comment: i put like this var id = ' ' ; nothing displayed

Comment: give me 5-10 mins, I will supply you with a jsfiddle with working sample code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5e79qkzL/ @JamesJim I stripped the code not required for the demonstration. But you should get how your code should look like.

Comment: This was intentional, see how the second example works?

Comment: secord one i show that sir ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: then how to get the id sir any other way

Comment: I am not sure you are right. If you click `get_category_details2(id)` then `addProject2()` you can see that the `tempID` is available and can be used.

Comment: Which part is so hard to understand? inside your javascript code put `var tempID = ''` outside the `get_category_details(id)` function then inside change `id = data.d[0].id;` to `tempID = data.d[0].id;` and then in `addProject()` change from `data: "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: '" + id + "'}",` to `data: "{fname: '" + $('#fname').val() + "',age: '" + $('#age').val() + "', id: '" + tempID + "'}",`